# Persist Eclipse perspective layout in new window

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen and have arranged the tabs of my perspectives the way I prefer.  When I close/re-open eclipse, this perspective layout persists.

If I select a project then select Window->New Window, the layout is not persistent.  The same is also true from the mouse right-click context menu.  There seems to be no setting in Window->Preferences->General-> Perspectives/Workspace to modify this behavior.

Does anyone know how to enforce the layout of a perspective across New Window command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guide](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-43e.htm) helped me out. Just go to Window > Perspective > Save Perspective As. Choose Resource and click OK. It worked for me.

Comment: That indeed did it.  I did not make a connection between saving a perspective as a resource.  Thanks.